# ¿Cómo cambio el cursor de texto en visual studio code | macOs?

Tags: macos, vscode, cursor

De alguna manera terminé con un rectángulo en lugar de la línea que tiene por default.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda <3

Comment: Te fijaste en las preferencias de diseño de codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso lo tienes en Code -> Preferences/Preferencias -> Settings/Configuración -> y en el campo de buscar escribe "cursor" te llevará a Text Editor /Editor de texto y debajo dice Cursor. En Cursor Style /Estilo de cursor tienes ahora puesto block o bloque. Cámbialo por el que quieras.
[image: aquí tienes un ejemplo]